# JSTL c:if tag condition

Tags: java, jstl

```
<c:if test="${config.update and not config.caseUpdate}">
        <html:submit property="userComments" style="width:200px" styleId="addCommentsBtn">
               <bean:message key="button.update.case"/>
        </html:submit>
</c:if>
```

I am confusing about this working mechanism . Can you please explain on if condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will execute

`<html:submit property="userComments" style="width:200px" styleId="addCommentsBtn">
               <bean:message key="button.update.case.with.comments"/>
        </html:submit>`

only when `config.update` will true and `config.caseUpdate` will false

example

`<c:if test='condition'>
    Generate some template text 
</c:if>`

if condition is true it will display template text.

if you want to display gender as male if condition is gender male then you can print male in c:if

for more information go through http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core/if.html

Comment: Befor i did't understand that `and not`. Good Explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://heavyz.sourceforge.net/homepage/homepage_zh/comp/notes/jstl-core.html) you can read about jstl scopes and statements.

Answer (score 0):

This is like saying

```
if(config.update && !config.caseUpdate){
  show a submit button
}
```

JSTL also works by checking if those variables are null. So if one is null it wont do anything.

Example, you can do something like

```
${config.update}
```

to print to the web browser the object config.update. If config.update is null or basically doesn't exist yet in the session, then it simply skips over it so you get no errors.